# Module complied with swift 5.1 cannot be imported by the swift 5.4 complier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, clover

Im trying to integrate Clover- Go SDK as per this
https://github.com/clover/remote-pay-ios-go

But get the following error "Module complied with swift 5.1 cannot be imported by the swift 5.4 complier".
I'm using `Xcode 12.5`

**pod file**

pod 'Starscream', :git => 'https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream.git', :tag => '3.0.5'
pod 'GoConnector', '3.3.5'

Gone through google and found many answers to set `Build Libraries for Distribution -> YES` in project Target, but its not working.

Please advice what can be done to make the app compile without errors

EDIT :
As per some of the suggested solutions I tried downloading XCode Toolchains (swift 4.2) and build the app.
[image]

But it fails with the below error [image]

Comment: There is an open [issue](https://github.com/clover/remote-pay-ios-go/issues/9) that highlights your problem. Unfortunately you need the makers of the SDK to update it so that you can use it in your application. I suggest you reach out to them, and perhaps also add to the existing issue.

Comment: Then you need to use a previous version that was compiled with Swift 5.1.

Comment: @Andrew I have tried one of the possible way, but get error. Could you advice

Comment: As I said you need the developer of the SDK update it. I would not advise using an older tool chain as even if you get it to work, you may have issues when submitting to the App Store and all you will have done is in prolonged your pain.

Answer (score 0):

Swift binaries are not compatible between swift 5.1 and 5.4 ("not compatible" here used as a proxy for the real explanation, which is complicated, but true-enough for your purposes).

So there's no "make this work with 5.4" to make an old 5.1 binary linkable with new 5.4 code.

Your two possible solutions involve replacing either the 5.1 code or the 5.4 code:

1. As Andrew said, get the pod authors to build a new binary, get access to the code and do it yourself. (Not likely, pod authors don't work for you, likely won't just give you their code.)
2. Change your build, by altering your Xcode toolchain to tell it to build with a different swift version (possible, not trivial). See:

https://medium.com/xcblog/switching-swift-versions-inside-xcode-using-toolchains-755b28831c43

Comment: Like you said I downloaded Xcode Toolchain swift 4.2 , switched to it in Preferences and build the app, but it fails with these errors.                <unknown>:0: error: unknown argument: '-enable-library-evolution'
<unknown>:0: error: unknown argument: '-emit-module-interface-path'
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code